CreateService Windows API does not work properly with serviceid that starts with a "-"
I have some code that tries to install a service on Windows using the following API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicea
I have lpBinaryPathName variable that contains the path to the executable and command line arguments, where arg1 is the serviceid.
Relevant code:
IntPtr service = CreateService(scm, serviceName, displayName, ServiceAccessRights.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, startuptype, ServiceError.SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, lpBinaryPathName, null, IntPtr.Zero, dependencies, account, passwordPointer);

where lpBinaryPathName="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\INSTALLDIR -100\"";
I am not getting any error messages when performing this operation and the service appears to be installed correctly in a stopped state. However, when I try to start the service after installation, my main.cpp file inside the executable is not run for some reason. I verified this by adding print statements inside my main function.
I've tested this with different variations of lpBinaryPathName and they all work just fine. Only when my serviceid starts with a '-' does the service refuse to start.

I have a hunch that the CreateService function is treating the -100 as
a command line parameter option instead of a value for the serviceid.
I tried escaping it with '\' but to no avail.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to troubleshoot this issue?

First clarify if you're using C# or C++, you talk about C# but your code and files are cpp. Rookie mistake & you've been around a bit....

From the docs: If the path contains a space, it must be quoted. Looks like you missed the required quotes.

@JeremyThompson My apologies for not being clear. I have a WPF C# application that creates and installs the service that the code above is taken from. I mention a main.cpp file because the .exe that is generated for the service is a c++ project. However it never enters the main.cpp file upon service start when serviceid has a '-' in the beginning. "a-b" serviceid works normally.

@user8463863 why are you setting the lpBinaryPathName to a directory and not the .exe file?

If the path to the executable contains spaces you need to quote the path. Then append the command line arguments. In this case, you'll want lpBinaryPathName to be something like "\"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\My Service.exe\" -100"

According to the official sample: Installing a Service
// In case the path contains a space, it must be quoted so that
// it is correctly interpreted. For example,
// "d:\my share\myservice.exe" should be specified as
// ""d:\my share\myservice.exe"".
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
StringCbPrintf(szPath, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\"%s\""), szUnquotedPath);

lpBinaryPathName="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\INSTALLDIR -100\""

I've updated the question to include the accurate code that includes the extra slashes in the string. My code does work for serviceids "200" "1" "abc" "123", but fails for "-100", "-1". Interestingly enough "a-b" works too. There is something going on here that I am missing.

To prevent issue with commands, I suggest you should avoid using spaces and special characters together.
